# Remote Control Other Devices Running Evernote

Tags: remote-access, tablet, evernote

I'm looking for a solution to remotely control a collection of devices running evernote from my tablet.  For example, we have several musicians on stage that read from Evernote during a live performance and I would like their tablets to load the same note that I choose from my tablet.  This hands free functionality is very important to our musicians.

I have a degree in computer programming so I don't mind writing code, I just need someone to tell me if this is possible with Evernote's api.  Thanks in advance for the advice.

Comment: Would it be possible to create a HTML page that just pings for changes in a DB (as a command and control server), and if that DB entry changes, then the HTML page can load content via ajax?
https://dev.evernote.com/doc/#reference

Comment: That's an interesting idea.  So maybe use the viewNote event to trigger a call to database?  During a performance, I wouldn't be 'changing' a note but merely opening a note to view its contents

Comment: Yeah, something like that. I know it's different to what you were thinking, but it'd probably be the easiest way. I'd do it the following way... hang on. I'll write it in an answer...

Answer (score 0):

Following on, I'd set it up the following way:

Have the main database which will act as the main controlling point. In it's simplest form, you'll probably only need 3 fields or similar.

```
TABLE: WhatRecord
  WR_ID - INT
  WR_EN_ID - varchar
  WR_DATE - datetime
```

You have an admin site (section) that would be able to save to the database, the current EverNote record ID for the clients to pull.

Each client page, would just poll the database for a change every 5 seconds or so. 
If that record ID or date changed, then the page, would download the new record ID.

It'll probably take a little bit to set up, but shouldn't be too complicated.